# Make h2 inside div also change colour like the rest

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the colour of an `h2` tag inside a `div`.
The other elements inside this `div` change to white colour when hovered over, only the `h2` does not change colour.
I know I can change this in CSS... `.well.sb:hover, .well.sb:hover h2`, but the bad thing with that is that the `h2` part changes colour separately from the rest. When hovering over the whole thing, everything (including h2) should change text-color into white at the same time and at the same speed and for the same one big and only div section. How to make that work?

```css
h2.title-article-sidebar {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Calibri;
    color: #444;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.article-image-summary-sidebar {
    border: 0 solid;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    -moz-transition: .9s ease;
    -webkit-transition: .9s ease;
    -o-transition: .9s ease;
    -ms-transition: .9s ease;
    transition: .9s ease;
}

.well.sb:hover {
        color: #FFF;
        background-color: #A10000;
        text-decoration: none;
        -moz-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
        transition: .6s ease-in-out;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="well sb"><div>
      
        <div class="article-image-summary-sidebar">
            <img alt="X" src="http://loremxpixel.com/200/200">
            <div class="article-date-summary-sidebar">
                20-November-2010
                
            </div>
            <div class="article-tag-summary-sidebar">
                TAG
            </div>
            <h2 class="title-article-sidebar">
               TITLE WITH H2 TAG!!!!
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things happening. First, you need to target the h2 more specifically (it's overriding your hover styles). Second, you have conflicting transitions.

```css
h2.title-article-sidebar {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Calibri;
    color: #444;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.article-image-summary-sidebar {
    border: 0 solid;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    /* -moz-transition: .9s ease;
    -webkit-transition: .9s ease;
    -o-transition: .9s ease;
    -ms-transition: .9s ease;
    transition: .9s ease; */
}

.well.sb:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #A10000;
    text-decoration: none;
    -moz-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
    transition: .6s ease-in-out;
}
.well.sb:hover h2.title-article-sidebar {
    color: #FFF;
    -moz-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
    transition: .6s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="well sb"><div>
      
    <div class="article-image-summary-sidebar">
        <img alt="X" src="http://loremxpixel.com/200/200">
        <div class="article-date-summary-sidebar">
            20-November-2010
            
        </div>
        <div class="article-tag-summary-sidebar">
            TAG
        </div>
        <h2 class="title-article-sidebar">
           TITLE WITH H2 TAG!!!!
        </h2>
    </div>

</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove color: #444; from h2.title-article-sidebar

Comment: the color is meant to CHANGE as I clearly wrote in my description, not stay the same.

Comment: of course the color will change to white if you remove that style

Answer (score 0):

Recent version of chrome tend to add transitions in nested elements (not sure about it is a bug or a feature).

Just make sure that children don't have an inherited transition

```css
h2.title-article-sidebar {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  color: #444;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.article-image-summary-sidebar {
  border: 0 solid;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  -moz-transition: .9s ease;
  -webkit-transition: .9s ease;
  -o-transition: .9s ease;
  -ms-transition: .9s ease;
  transition: .9s ease;
}
.well.sb:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #A10000;
  text-decoration: none;
  -moz-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
  transition: .6s ease-in-out;
}
.sb * {
  transition: 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="well sb">
  <div>

    <div class="article-image-summary-sidebar">
      <img alt="X" src="http://loremxpixel.com/200/200">
      <div class="article-date-summary-sidebar">
        20-November-2010

      </div>
      <div class="article-tag-summary-sidebar">
        TAG
      </div>
      <h2 class="title-article-sidebar">
               TITLE WITH H2 TAG!!!!
            </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve it:

```css
h2.title-article-sidebar {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Calibri;
    /* color: #444;*/
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.article-image-summary-sidebar {
    border: 0 solid;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

.well.sb:hover {
        color: #FFF;
        background-color: #A10000;
        text-decoration: none;
        -moz-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
        transition: .6s ease-in-out;
    }
```

```html
<div class="well sb"><div>
      
        <div class="article-image-summary-sidebar">
            <img alt="X" src="http://loremxpixel.com/200/200">
            <div class="article-date-summary-sidebar">
                20-November-2010
                
            </div>
            <div class="article-tag-summary-sidebar">
                TAG
            </div>
            <h2 class="title-article-sidebar">
               TITLE WITH H2 TAG!!!!
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div></div>
```

Comment: I don't think the user is looking for this as he clearly mentioned to change the colour. @Andre

Comment: I don't think he wants this either. He has already downvoted one answer suggesting what you are explaining here. Commenting `#444` isn't I think the user is looking for. @Andre

Comment: I guess this is the best option. I removed the animation from `.article-image-summary-sidebar ` class. and now the animation is ok.

Comment: You must be kidding right. Add that `#444` back into the code and see how your working fails. @Andre

Comment: I've focus on the transition and forgot to add the color back :D
Anyway, @mhatch already answered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any problem in your animation as mentioned in some other answers. You have correctly written your code nor there is any `specificity` problem.

I am attaching a codepen link on which I was trying to solve your problem:
http://codepen.io/Sky-123/pen/mALGQZ

The animations remains intact as you have written them. The only change that I did was added the `color:#444` to `h2` tag through an inline statement and then removed it on `hover` in `jQuery` as it was causing concerns in animation..

Hope it solves your problem.